# Coordinate algorithm

Tags: algorithm, coordinates

I am creating a 2D game and came across a specific problem. Imagine having a huuuge board with thousands of object on it. Now I want to update the state of objects every frame. But it's stupid to update all of these objects. OK, a trivial approach is to iterate over elements and check - if the distance is satisfying, THEN update. But that's slow. If I have let's say 1.000.000 objects and after the loop only about 100 of them will be updated, that suggests this is a naive algorithm. I need some algorithm that would enable me to simply get those 100 elements, or even 500.

Some sort of a hashmap? And the hascode for coordinates would be like:

```
(x / 100) * 100
```

That gives something like "packages". But I doubt it will provide a significant increase in performance. Do you have any ideas? Some ingenious algorithms?

Comment: If you go the hashmap route, are you looking to recreate the data-structure (based on your point about the hashcode)?

Comment: After getting the right packages, I would have to iterate over objects inside and get their coordinates out and then check the distances. If that's what you were asking for.

Comment: split terrain into squares; for each square keep list objects in it; when updating consider only the squares that are within the required distance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comment: What you are describing is not just your need to have a coordinate algorithm, but to also recreate a fundamental data-structure for it. Hashes/Hash-maps/ArrayMappings (however you're used to calling them), already exist. You don't need to deal with the hashcode, packages, etc. The data-structure will handle that for you.

Comment: Your problem may be resolved by simple clipping. You may be interested in quadtrees, which are recursive structure useful to subdivide 2D area. cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree .

Comment: Your description is lacking essential information: how do you know which objects "really" needs an update ? From your minimalist explanation we can infer that you only want to update the objects that are in view, but this is just an hypothesis. You also give no clue on the size/shape/distribution/representation of these objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a trivial approach would be to split your world into zones, each by the size of the screen, and update only the zone where your player is, and 8 zones around it. If your world is really huge, that will work, if not - you probably need a smarter solution.

Really depends on your requirements, but I would have at least tried it as it is very simple, and will give you lots of performance gain compared to iterating.